# Accessing HttpApplicationState

Tags: asp.net

Can it be done outside of Global.asax?  I stored some app state info on app_start that I want to grab in a controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["key"]
```